# Ehcache 2.10 Thread BLOCKED

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, ehcache, ehcache-2

Ehcache version

2.10.6

Once in a while, Ehcache servers are getting down because of the threads getting blocked. Please find below the details about the bucket configuration and thread details which are blocking each other.

There are multiple buckets:
Bucket configuration

```
<cache name="bucket1"
           maxBytesLocalHeap="300m"
           maxBytesLocalDisk="15g"
           timeToIdleSeconds="240"
           timeToLiveSeconds="240"
           eternal="false"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="360"
           transactionalMode="off"
           diskPersistent="true">
    </cache>
```

**Thread dump**

```
http-nio-8080-exec-26
Stack Trace is:
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault.get(OnHeapCachingTier.java:332)
- **waiting to lock <0x0000000604407968>** (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault.access$200(OnHeapCachingTier.java:312)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier.getValue(OnHeapCachingTier.java:300)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier.access$000(OnHeapCachingTier.java:62)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$1.evicted(OnHeapCachingTier.java:84)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.PooledBasedBackEnd$1.removed(PooledBasedBackEnd.java:195)
at net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.internalReplace(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1346)
at net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.removeAndNotify(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2647)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.PooledBasedBackEnd.remove(PooledBasedBackEnd.java:113)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier.remove(OnHeapCachingTier.java:207)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore.put(CacheStore.java:134)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.putInternal(Cache.java:1616)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1542)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1507)......



http-nio-8080-exec-174
Stack Trace is:
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node.tryAwaitLock(ConcurrentHashMap.java:687)
- locked <0x00000005fa31d820> (a net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node)
at net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.internalReplace(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1311)
at net.sf.ehcache.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.remove(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2643)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.PooledBasedBackEnd.evict(PooledBasedBackEnd.java:159)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.PooledBasedBackEnd$PoolParticipant.evict(PooledBasedBackEnd.java:251)
at net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.FromLargestCachePoolEvictor.freeSpace(FromLargestCachePoolEvictor.java:49)
at net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.AtomicPoolAccessor.add(AtomicPoolAccessor.java:71)
at net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.AbstractPoolAccessor.add(AbstractPoolAccessor.java:67)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.Segment.put(Segment.java:427)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.disk.DiskStore.putFaulted(DiskStore.java:229)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore$3.call(CacheStore.java:143)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore$3.call(CacheStore.java:137)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault.get(OnHeapCachingTier.java:335)
**- locked <0x0000000604407968> (a net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault)**
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier$Fault.access$200(OnHeapCachingTier.java:312)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.cachingtier.OnHeapCachingTier.get(OnHeapCachingTier.java:176)
at net.sf.ehcache.store.CacheStore.put(CacheStore.java:137)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.putInternal(Cache.java:1616)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1542)
at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1507)
.......
```

Comment: Can you add more details as code or system ? do you use Spring/Hibernate/other?  is there a load on your server or specific endpoint?

Comment: No I am directly using ehcache through jar. Neither through hibernate nor through spring annotation

Comment: can you show code or explain when you add to cache?

Comment: It is a rest application meant just for caching, On PUT request, content is put into cache with the mentioned with simple vanilla syntax cache.put(Element). Load is on higher side sometimes reaching 50K requests per min (GET +PUT) . 16GB RAM, 100GB disk for caching

Comment: @user7294900, 2 put threads are locking a resource, i am sensing something related to eviction. Can you work it out, as i am not sure

Comment: Please share your code as well

Comment: Hi @Ajit, It is rest application on tomcat. Simple cache.put and cache.get is used. APIS: PUT /cache/key payload and GET /cache/key .without any use of hibernate, spring cacheable

Comment: not a real explanation but ... we had the same problem we fixed it by upgrading to ehcache 3.x (3.6 at the time)

Comment: Thanks @benbenw, We are doing the same migrating to 3.8 . Your response serve as a  good testimony for least.

Comment: @benbenw, Can we discuss about migration on the chatroom: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment, I don't have a real explanation but ...

We had the same problem with ehcache 2.10.5 : only heap cache and hibernate and standalone usage.

We fixed it by upgrading to ehcache 3.x (3.6 at the time).

We didn't investigate the issue on the 2.10 as it was an outdated version.